# What is the C++ equivalent to C formatting "%3d"?

Tags: c++

My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int total=0;

    while(count<=10)
    {   
        total=total+count;   
        cout<<"count"<<"="<<count/*<<','*/<<'\t'<<'\t'<<"total"<<"="<<total<<endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the ouput you expect?

Comment: Use I/O manipulators (e.g. [`setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)).

Comment: when count=9  total=45

Comment: when when count=10 the formatting of total is changed

Comment: in 'c' we use %3d for 3 spaces what is used in c++ instead of this

Comment: You mean you want 1 to come out as `  1` and 12 to come out as ` 12` - padding?

Comment: I feel like no one here knows what `printf("%3d", 42);` does. It is a clear and easy question, yet people keep posting weird answers and io manipulators.

Comment: What is unclear about his question?

Comment: voted to reopen, question is clear and contains an attempt

Answer (score 3):

All of the facilities of the C standard library are still available in C++.  You can write your program like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
using std::printf;

int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  int total = 0;

  while (count<=10)
  {   
    total = total + count;
    printf("count=%3d, total=%3d\n", count, total); 
    count++;
  }
}
```

It is my personal opinion that the `stdio.h` output interfaces are nearly always easier to use and produce more readable code than the `iostream` output interfaces, particularly for formatted output of numbers (as in this case), so I would not hesitate to do so.  The major advantage of `iostream` is that it can be extended to format *objects* via `operator<<` overloads, but a program like this does not need that.

Note that neither the `stdio.h` nor the `iostream` *input* interfaces are fit for purpose, due to egregious, standard-codified bugs like defining numeric input overflow to trigger undefined behavior (I am not making this up!)

Comment: (Not my down-vote, but…) While correct at one level, it isn't very helpful since the OP is clearly asking about using the C++ `<iostream>` formatting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is a fair criticism and I am happy to have this answer lose the reputation game to an answer that actually uses `iostream`s, but I think it is valuable to document that you don't *have* to use `iostream`s in C++ if you don't want to.

Comment: @Zack It's not so much that you want to use iostream; it's that no one in their right mind would use `printf` if they could avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Using iostream formatting, you need to include the `iomanip` header and use the [`setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [`setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int count=0;
    int total=0;

    while(count<=10)
    {   
        total=total+count;   
        cout<<"count"<<"="<<count<<'\t'<<'\t'<<"total"<<"="<<setfill(' ')<<setw(3)<<total<<endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `setfill` for? As far as I can tell ' ' is the default filler, so it does nothing.

Comment: `setfill` defines which character will be used if the input "string length" is lesser than the value specified by `setw`. It is a good practice using `setfill` to say _explicitly_ that you want that character as a filler, since it is compiler-dependent and it changes the state of the stream, instead of just the next input (`setw`) - meaning that if you had a previous call like `setfill('0')`, you need to _reset_ it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setw` and `left` from [iomanip](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) to achive the effect you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int total=0;

    while(count<=10)
    {
        total=total+count;
        std::cout << "count = " << std::setw(15) << std::right << count << "total = " << total << std::endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

`setw` set the with of the next "cout impression" (15 in this case) and `left` just set the aligment to the left.

**Note:** As suggest by @Zack you can write `<< '\n'` at the end instead `<< endl`. Since `<< endl` is exactly the same as writing `<< '\n' << flush` and the flush isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Suggest `<< '\n'` at the end instead.  `<< endl` is exactly the same as writing `<< '\n' << flush` and the flush isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Why did you use `setw(15)` instead of `setw(3)`? Why `left`? Why  `using namespace std;` globally?
The line in question should be something like
`cout << "count = " << setw(3) << count << "\ttotal = " << setw(3) << total << '\n';` to make it do the same as `%3d`.

Comment: @nwp The code I post is an example on how to achive some formatting. You can suggest `setw(3)` if you want it really does not have any relevance here. About `left` well, Have you tried the code without it? I don't think so.

Comment: I tried it. And it does what it says, it puts the numbers left aligned, which looks bad. "%3d" does not do that. The title of the question clearly asks how to do "%3d" formatting and this is a good answer that basically shows that, but it feels ruined by using the wrong modifiers.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about the question says, but this is not only about what the question says, this is about try to help, and if there are others solutions out there we have to expose them. Talking about formatting you can achive the "%3d" effect with the proposed functions. But if you have a better solution, please be welcome to post it.

Comment: better not bring a total namespace std to scope

Comment: @bits_international, you're right, answer has been edited, `nwp` advised me about that too, thanks to both.

Comment: I don't mean to talk down your answer. I didn't answer because my answer would have been basically the same as yours. I also thought you mistyped some parts and would fix it. Also I am wondering where the 15 comes from, because another answer also uses `setw(15)`. And about the `left`: The default is `right` which has the same behavior as "%3d", so you intentionally made `cout` behave differently than what the formatting in question wanted. I don't get why you did that so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ IO formatting is being done either in same way as in C (since all C functionalities are in place also in C++) or with `std::setw` `std::setprecission` and other C++ [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) presented in header .

So either of this will be fine:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int total=0;

    while( count <= 10)
    {
        total += count;
        printf( "count = %3d, total = %3d\n", count++, total);
    }
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int total=0;

    while( count <= 10)
    {
        total += count;
        std::cout << "count = " << std::setw(15) << 
                        count++ << "total = " << total << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also do custom formatting by `imbue` to apply custom facet to [locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale) ( i.e. extend std::numpunct).

http://ideone.com/nHfTL6

Comment: dude, you have copied my answer!!! Your code not even use functions you're suggesting (`setprecission`).

Comment: @RaydelMiranda do you mean content of <iostream> and <iomanip>?